# Unable to resolve groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine

Tags: maven, groovy

Trying to use groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine in the Groovy based unit tests of my Maven based project with gmaven plugin configured as following

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmaven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5-jenkins-3</version>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.12</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
      </plugin>
```

My command line build `mvn clean install` fails not being able to compile my simple Groovy unit test file with an error message

> [ERROR]
>   file:/Users/../my-service/src/test/groovy/myapp/MyApplicationTest.groovy:
>   84: unable to resolve class groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine [ERROR] @
>   line 84, column 30. [ERROR] XmlTemplateEngine engine = new
>   groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine() [ERROR] ^

And in the file I'm only doing a simple command

```
import groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine
...
XmlTemplateEngine engine = new groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine()
```

Both lines fail with the same error message.
The version of Groovy installed in my OSX command line is 2.4.12.

Comment: That should work, but strange.

Comment: Yeah, the rest of the Groovy code compiles very well except of this XmlTemplateEngine line(s)

Comment: According to the mvn -e -X output the groovy-all-2.4.12.jar doesn't come to the classpath during compiltion at all.
Only groovy-2.4.11.jar (coming from a transitive dependency I guess) is available. And the groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine is not part of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have analyzed the output of the

```
mvn -e -X test
```

command and didn't find the groovy-all.jar on the classpath during the test compilation phase. Only groovy.jar was present and it doesn't contain `groovy.text.XmlTemplateEngine` class.

So, I added an additional test dependency:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

And it compiles my tests well now.